# Can I develop .net 4.5 app using vs2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have installed .net 4.5 framework from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

After installing the 4.5 framework I restarted the machine. In vs 2010 if any new project is created by default 4.0 framework is assigned in project properties Application->Target framework is assigned as .NET Framework 4.0. But I want to change to 4.5 framework. But 4.5 framework is not listed.

My question is , should i do some settings changes to list 4.5 framework in vs2010 or i can't develope any app using .net 4.5 in vs2010?

Thanks 
Saran

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, you can't target .NET 4.5 with VS2010 the same way you couldn't target .NET 4.0 with VS2008. You will need to install VS2012 if you want to target .NET 4.5.