# Targeting .NET Framework 4.5 via Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.5

Today I installed the .NET Framework 4.5 on my machine expecting to be able to use it from Visual Studio 2010, since it's just a minor update that should't pose problems for Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately I am not, even manually removing certain 4.0 and adding the corresponding 4.5 assemblies resulted in the original 4.0 assemblies still being referenced in the project.

Is it possible to target version 4.5 from Visual Studio 2010 and if yes, how? I'd really like to use the ribbons...

Comment: You must upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 for .NET v4.5 support.

Comment: I came to know about this limitation when I was trying to use System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run() method in a VS 2010 console application. This method doesn't show up on Task class if your project is targeting .Net framework 4.0 and then you realize that VS2010 can not target .Net framework 4.5 if you want.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Each version of Visual Studio prior to Visual Studio 2010 is tied to a specific .NET framework. (VS2008 is .NET 3.5, VS2005 is .NET 2.0, VS2003 is .NET1.1) Visual Studio 2010 and beyond allow for targeting of prior framework versions but cannot be used for future releases. You must use Visual Studio 2012 in order to utilize .NET 4.5.

Comment: Not entirely true -- .NET 3.0 was released between VS versions, and could be used in VS2005.

Comment: True, but only by way of an extension. It wasn't built into VS 2005 from the beginning (and, as such, not fully optimized).

Comment: What a conundrum: migrate to vs2012+ to utilize a nicety of .net 4.5 at the cost of losing the beloved vs2010 Setup Project for deploying msi installers... "upgrade" feels more like a sidegrade...

Comment: @ecoe - There is a VS 2013 extension that brings back the Setup & Deployment project type: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: And don't forget to mention horrendous search in Visual studio above 2010

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not have to upgrade to use this feature. All you need to do is add a new reference, then browse to the .NET 4.5 folder: 
C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\\.Net Framework\4.5. You will find the reference in there. Just add it and it works

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus - What "feature" are you referring to, and which of the items in that `...\4.5` folder do we add?

Comment: @JeffRoe sorry for the delay. You can add whichever namespace assembly contains the method you need. I was working with ZIP files and needed to add the "System.IO.Compression" dll.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus in VS 2010 I click "Target Framework=Install Other Frameworks" and it takes me to a website https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks It does not let me navigate to any folder. What should i do. i must be able to target 4.5 from VS 2010. Tks.

Comment: I only have a v3.0 and v3.5 directory, not a v4.0 or 4.5 directory.  How do I get the necessary files placed there?  In ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v4.5```

Answer (score 69):

There are pretty limited scenarios that I can think of where this would be useful, but let's assume you can't get funds to purchase VS2012 or something to that effect.  If that's the case and you have Windows 7+ and VS 2010 you may be able to use the following hack I put together which seems to work (but I haven't fully deployed an application using this method yet).

1. **Backup your project file!!!**
2. Download and install the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) which includes the .NET 4.5 SDK.
3. Open your project in VS2010.
4. Create a text file in your project named `Compile_4_5_CSharp.targets` with the following contents.  (Or just download it [here](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=g3f90CQZ) - Make sure to remove the ".txt" extension from the file name):

   ```
   <Project DefaultTargets="Build"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

       <!-- Change the target framework to 4.5 if using the ".NET 4.5" configuration -->
       <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '.NET 4.5' ">
           <DefineConstants Condition="'$(DefineConstants)'==''">
               TARGETTING_FX_4_5
           </DefineConstants>
           <DefineConstants Condition="'$(DefineConstants)'!='' and '$(DefineConstants)'!='TARGETTING_FX_4_5'">
               $(DefineConstants);TARGETTING_FX_4_5
           </DefineConstants>
           <PlatformTarget Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)'!=''"/>
           <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
       </PropertyGroup>

       <!-- Import the standard C# targets -->
       <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

       <!-- Add .NET 4.5 as an available platform -->
       <PropertyGroup>
          <AvailablePlatforms>$(AvailablePlatforms),.NET 4.5</AvailablePlatforms>
       </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
5. Unload your project (right click -> unload).
6. Edit the project file (right click -> Edit *.csproj).
7. Make the following changes in the project file:

   a. Replace the default `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` with the target file created in step 4

   ```
   <!-- Old Import Entry -->
   <!-- <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> -->

   <!-- New Import Entry -->
   <Import Project="Compile_4_5_CSharp.targets" />
   ```

   b. Change the default platform to `.NET 4.5`

   ```
   <!-- Old default platform entry -->
   <!-- <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform> -->

   <!-- New default platform entry -->
   <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">.NET 4.5</Platform>
   ```

   c. Add `AnyCPU` platform to allow targeting other frameworks as specified in the project properties.  This should be added just before the first `<ItemGroup>` tag in the file

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'">
       <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>

   .
   .
   .
   <ItemGroup>
   .
   .
   .
   ```
8. Save your changes and close the `*.csproj` file.
9. Reload your project (right click -> Reload Project).
10. In the configuration manager (Build -> Configuration Manager) make sure the ".NET 4.5" platform is selected for your project.
11. Still in the configuration manager, create a new solution platform for ".NET 4.5" (you can base it off "Any CPU") and make sure ".NET 4.5" is selected for the solution.
12. Build your project and check for errors.
13. Assuming the build completed you can verify that you are indeed targeting 4.5 by adding a reference to a 4.5 specific class to your source code:

    ```
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    namespace testing
    {
        using net45check = System.Reflection.ReflectionContext;
    }
    ```
14. When you compile using the ".NET 4.5" platform the build should succeed.  When you compile under the "Any CPU" platform you should get a compiler error:

    ```
    Error 6: The type or namespace name 'ReflectionContext' does not exist in
    the namespace 'System.Reflection' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    ```

Comment: this is krazy, even if it worked, would UI elements like ribbon designer work without masses of xaml and other errors? srsly just upgrade.

Comment: In addition to David Woodward's answer, I added: `<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>` to the first PropertyGroup, when the below error occurred: The OutputPath property is not set for project 'project name'.

Comment: This indeed works. But I'm just using it so I can keep running Moles on VS2010 after installing .NET Framework 4.5.1.

Comment: I was unable to figure out how to successfully do step 11, "...create a new solution platform...", but I found that the instructions were successful overall if step 11 is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

FYI, if you want to create an Installer package in VS2010, unfortunately it only targets .NET 4. To work around this, you have to add NET 4.5 as a launch condition.

Add the following in to the Launch Conditions of the installer (Right click, View, Launch Conditions).

In "Search Target Machine", right click and select "Add Registry Search".

```
Property: REGISTRYVALUE1
RegKey: Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
Root: vsdrrHKLM
Value: Release
```

Add new "Launch Condition":

```
Condition: REGISTRYVALUE1>="#378389"
InstallUrl: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653
Message: Setup requires .NET Framework 4.5 to be installed.
```

Where:

378389 = .NET Framework 4.5

378675 = .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed with Windows 8.1

378758 = .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on Windows 8, Windows 7 SP1, or Windows Vista SP2

379893 = .NET Framework 4.5.2

Launch condition reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xxyh2e6a(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with VS2010/DNFW 4.5 integration and have finally got this working.  Starting in VS 2008, a cache of assemblies was introduced that is used by Visual Studio called the "Referenced Assemblies".  This file cache for VS 2010 is located at \Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NetFramework\v4.0.  Visual Studio loads framework assemblies from this location instead of from the framework installation directory.  When Microsoft says that VS 2010 does not support DNFW 4.5 what they *mean* is that this directory does not get updated when DNFW 4.5 is installed.  Once you have replace the files in this location with the updated DNFW 4.5 files, you will find that VS 2010 will happily function with DNFW 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

From another search. Worked for me!

"You can use Visual Studio 2010 and it does support it, provided your OS supports .NET 4.5.

Right click on your solution to add a reference (as you do). When the dialog box shows, select browse, then navigate to the following folder:

**C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.Net Framework\4.5**

You will find it there."

Comment: In the sentence "You will find it there", what is "it"?  Which file in that folder do we select?  Will one of them let us target .net 4.5 in VS 2010?

Comment: You will find the namespace assemblies. You can add whichever one you want. For example, I needed to use a method for working with ZIP files. So I found the dll "System.IO.Compression.dll" and added it to my project. Then I could explicitly list the namespace in my code and use the methods I needed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  If you remove your reference to, say, System, and then browse to the .Net 4.5 System.dll and add that as a reference, VS is still picks the 4.0 System.dll  Capt Nasty's answer on this page works for me, e.g. copy System.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6 and drop it on top of System.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0.  Note though that this is a nasty hack and may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

As a similar alternative to [David Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010/13240050#13240050)'s answer you can

1. Add a MyProject.csproj.user file to your project folder with the following content

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- choose the fx target framework sub version, here 4.5.2 -->
        <FrameworkVersion4FX>5</FrameworkVersion4FX>
        <FrameworkVersion4FXX Condition="$(FrameworkVersion4FX) != ''">2</FrameworkVersion4FXX>
        <TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX>v4</TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX>
        <TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX Condition="$(FrameworkVersion4FX) != '' ">$(TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX).$(FrameworkVersion4FX)</TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX>
        <TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX Condition="$(FrameworkVersion4FXX) != '' ">$(TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX).$(FrameworkVersion4FXX)</TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugNET4FX'">
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX)</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseNET4FX'">
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersionNET4FX)</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Reload the project
3. Open the configuration manager
4. The DebugNET4FX and ReleaseNET4FX configuration items appear now in the dropdown list of the project
5. Delete the both of the two new configurations by clicking "<Edit...>", selecting and "Remove" them
6. Click "<new...>" and add the both of them anew in the "New Project Configuration" window by typing the correct names, choosing the appropriate "Copy settings from" and leaving the box "Create new solution configurations" checked
7. Ensure that all configurations | platforms of the solution and the project are according to each other and the "Build" box is checked
8. Start the project

You can choose now in the solution dropdown the configuration | platform combination you want.