# how to add target framework to visual c# 2010 express

Tags: wpf, deployment

I have installed .net framework 4 but i can't see any changes in the project property window in the target framework list (i can only see 2,3,3.5). How to add 4 and 4.5. I would really appreciate any help because I have been working 2 days for this, and it's not yet fixed.

Comment: .net 4 come with vs2010, i wonder why you don't see it. unfortunately vs 2010 doesn't support 4.5 you need to update visual studio version

Comment: it supports 4.5, because it was so before i unstall it

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010/13240050#13240050

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting your computer after installing the .net framework?
If nothing helps you should update your vs to 2012, you can backup all your projects anyway :)

Comment: i restared and nothing changes, about upgrading to 2012 it's not necessary since i used to have 4 and 4.5 with 2010 version

Comment: @user2567191 if you keep having trouble maybe you should reinstall vs?