# Select ASP.Net framework 4.5 as target framework?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to set my projects framework target to ASP.Net 4.5 but am no able. 
I downloaded the ASP.Net 4.5 framework from the microsoft website but when i try install it i get the message:

> Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been
>   installed on this computer.

But if i look at my projects property page, Framework 4.0 is the highest i can select?

Please can someone tell me what i should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

It does not support with Visual Studio 2010. You need to have visual studio 2012.