# Cannot find .net Framework 4.0 or .net Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed. But I try to open a project in it, I cannot find .net Framework 4.0 or .net Framework 4.5 in the target framework. I have installed both. still I cannot find it. What am I suppose to do? Uninstalling Visual Studio is not an option for me.

Comment: You are missing the targeting packs.  c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies directory.  Impossible to guess how that could have happened of course, a VS install that is missing essential files is never a very good sign.

Comment: I looked there. I also can't figure it out how it happened./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayby you can install them using the tool menu in your visual studio.
Tools>extentions and update.
then search there for the 4.0 or 4.5 framwork versions

my bad the saluting is mentioned here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/… it seems to be a bit more difecult in vs2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/%E2%80%A6%20it%20seems%20to%20be%20a%20bit%20more%20difecult%20in%20vs2010)

Comment: It says "no items found"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010
it seems to be a bit more difecult in vs2010

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: "installing VS for Windows (not desktop!) u3"

I think with this your folder may appear and your original VS can start use them aswell as the new one