# Upgrade to .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: .net

I have visual studio 2010 installed on my machine which supports .net framework 4.0 and now I want to upgrade my framework to 4.5 in same VS2010...Can anyone please tell the steps to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SOF..This is not a programming issue @Pallavi, you should use SuperUser.com for this sort of issue.

Comment: You can't target framework 4.5 in VS 2010.   You'll need VS 2012 or later to target 4.5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Targeting .NET Framework 4.5 via Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010)