# Visual Studio Solution DLL error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, add-references-dialog

I have a visual studio solution which works fine on one machine and when I copy the complete same solution to another machine it misses few external dlls.
Both the machine have same configuration and same version of visual studio.

I tried removing reference and adding again.I am able to reference the dll and use code but when I re-build,It gives the same error.Any pointers on what could have gone wrong?

The error message I get is as below

> The type or namespace name 'NameSpaceName" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also the warning shows.

> The primary reference "NameSpaceName" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Both the machine have Visual Studio 2010 installed. It works on one and doesn't work on another machine

Answer (score 0):

The reference you have added to the project is likely not in a subfolder of your project but referenced from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). Since you probably didn't copy the GAC, this reference is now of a different version. Figure out which (3rd party ?) component is affected and install an older version of that component.

Typically, Visual Studio cannot target .NET 4.5, unless you applied a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010). In that case, you can go to the project properties, Application and change Target Framework from 4.0 to 4.5.

[image: Target Framework in Visual Studio properties]

Comment: The machine where solution works has VS 2010 and there also the framework is 4.0, still it is able to reference the dll which is 4.5. Moreover I do not get a version higher than 4 in dropdown

Comment: @CoolDiva: from where do you reference the DLL? Is it a DLL from GAC? In that case, install the same version of the 3rd party product as on the source PC.