# MSPL Script in Skype for Business 2015

Tags: c#, skype-for-business

I have a MSPL script running as a Server Application in a Lync Server 2013 system. The development of this application was done in c# referencing the library 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Lync Server 2013\SDK\Bin\ServerAgent.dll' which was installed with the MS Lync Server 2013 SDK.

I need to migrate this application to a Skype for Business 2015 system but I can't find the SfB equivalent of the Lync Server 2013 SDK.

Does anyone know how to compile a MSPL application in SfB 2015 ? I've read in various places that it should 'just work' in SfB but that would only be if I dropped the ServerAgent.dll in the same folder as the application on the SfB Front End Server and that seems like a hack.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Ed James

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In my case, using the old versions of "ServerAgent.dll" resulted in a strange behavior, as this typical piece of code to proxy the request was doing nothing:

```
ClientTransation ct = e.ServerTransaction.CreateBranch();

ct.SendRequest(e.Request);
```

In Skype for Business / Lync client, when establishing a new conversation (while my MSPL script was triggered on INVITE) the error "your message could not be transmitted" was appearing.

After investigation, and after trying to recompile my code on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with Skype for Business Server 2015 installed on it, it appeared that the new version of "ServerAgent.dll" (version 6.0.9319 located in Windows's GAC folder) had a dependency against another DLL which was in .NET Framework 4.5, while all my solution was built on .NET Framework 4.0.
To solve this issue, I recompiled in 4.5, but as I wanted to keep using Visual Studio 2010, I had to apply this solution (look for the second solution):

[Targeting .NET Framework 4.5 via Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010)

After that I finally managed to have it working correctly on Skype for Business 2015.