# MySql.Data not working on VB.net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, mysql-connector

I installed MySql connector version 6.8.8.0 and added MySql.Data reference on my Visual Studio 2010. Whenever I run my program, this warning message appears:

> The primary reference "MySql.Data,
>   Version-6.8.8.0, Culture neutral
>   PublicKeyToken c5687fc88969c44d
>   processorArchitecture-MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the "NETFramework Version-v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework "NETFramework, Version=v4.0 Profitee=Client".

Should I install an earlier version of MySql Connector?

Comment: The short answer is yes. [Because you can't use VS2010 to target .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12390581/4934172).