# Targeting .NET 4.5 in VS2010 on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I'd like to target .NET 4.5 in a VS2010 project on a new Widows 8 installation. I'm not given the option to target 4.5. In VS2012, I get that option, along with .NET 4. Is this something I should be able to do?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137450/can-i-develop-net-4-5-app-using-vs2010

Answer (score 2):

Just as you couldn't create .NET 4.0 projects in 2008, you can't target .NET 4.5 in VS 2010. It's not supported by the IDE.

Language compatibility goes backwards, not forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't target .NET 4.5 with Visual Studio 2010, since the reference assemblies used to compile your application are all .NET 4.0.   However, .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade for .NET 4.0, so at runtime you'd actually be using .NET 4.5 assemblies, you just won't have access to program some of the newer C# features like async/await.

Answer (score 0):

No, just like you can't target .NET 4 with VS 2008...

Comment: @il_guru, Why you edited 2008 to 2010? VS 2010 supports targeting .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Reverted to original statement that .NET 4 cannot be targeted with VS2008, not VS2010 as edited by @il_guru. il_guru, please do not edit again, if you disagree write your own answer or comment my original answer.

Comment: @DeanK. Dean i apologize. This edit was from over a year ago so i do not remember why I edited this. It clearly was a mistake, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Multi-targeting feature in Visual Studio is for targeting previously released versions of the .NET Framework (2.0 and above) and their service packs. You can't target future release of .NET Framework with previously released Visual Studio IDE.